# Python generic instance attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, pycharm

I have a class where in the `__init__` method I want to accept a generic value and set it as an instance attribute. I want the type of the attribute to be inferred from the value I had passed to the `__init__` in the type hinting of my IDE.

For example:

```
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

class Test:
    def __init__(self, a: T):
        self.a: T = a
```

Now, when I do

```
a = Test('a')
s = a.a
```

I want `s` to be inferred to be a string in Pycharm's type completion. Is that something that is possible in python?

edit:
I would like to do this without specifically inheriting from the Generic class

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=str)
```

[reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar)

EDIT: i just tried running your code and then i did `type(s)`. which gave me `<class 'str'>`. is this not what you want? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want it to only be a string, I want to be any type, and for the type to be inferred from the given value.

Comment: What do you mean @jondoe? Your code already states the type that was inputted.

Comment: That was just for the example. If I had supplied an int instead I would have wanted `s` to be inferred as `int`

Comment: @jondoe it already seems to do that. i did `b = Test(1)`, and then `type(b.a)`, which gave me `<class 'int'>`. is this not what you want?

Comment: the `type` function would always return the type of the value at runtime. I want to know if I could have a hint for the type of the value before running the code, in my IDE.

Comment: @jondoe that seems like an ide issue and not really an issue with python. if the ide can't detect variable types or something then you can't really do anything about that. i don't know why that matters anyways.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, just for ease of development for type hinting.